# TFS API WIQL Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, tfs, wiql

How can I validate a WIQL string without throw/catch exceptions?

I am working on a WPF application that takes the output of many manual WIQL or stored TFS queries and combines them into a single report.

One feature I'm implementing is through the UI adding a `WIQL string` directly and adding it to the report list.

Before adding it I want to validate that the `WIQL` is a valid string 
Currently I do the following:

```
public bool ManualWqlIsQuery(string wiql)
{
    try
    {
        var projectBinding = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "project", TfsShared.Instance.ProjectInfo.Name } };
        var query = new Query(TfsShared.Instance.WorkItemStore, wiql, projectBinding);
        Debug.WriteLine("Query Validated : Is Link {0} ; Is Tree {1}", query.IsLinkQuery, query.IsTreeQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've looked into both `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage` libraries to validate the text itself `Without` throw/catch `Exceptions` as my validation system, but no luck.